# Updating multiple properties in a JSON column in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server that contains a `nvarchar(max)` column containing JSON. I need to update an arbitrary number of properties in the JSON in each row.

Oracle and MySQL both support [`JSON_MERGE_PATCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-patch), which seems like it would be ideal.

I thought about using a table of `| id | jsonPath | value |` and performing an update join:

```
UPDATE 
    T
SET 
    T.Json = JSON_MODIFY(T.Json, Updates.jsonPath, Updates.value)
FROM 
    T INNER JOIN Updates
ON 
    T.id = Updates.id
```

before realising that this would (non-deterministically) apply only one update to each row.

What are my options?

Updated:
The JSON values are almost arbitrary documents. (As it happens, they won't contain arrays, but may contain arbitrary levels of nested objects).

When my application (c#) has some updates to apply, it won't know what properties already exist in any given document. Nor is there a fixed limit on how many properties it may need to update.

Obviously, to perform an update, I could first read the current json documents from the database, perform the json merge in my application, then push the results back to the database, but I'd prefer not to have to do that.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your JSON document before and after the desired change.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The JSON documents could be almost anything (though they don't contain arrays). I don't know at design time what properties they may have, or how many properties I might need to update/add.

Comment: According to the sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 unfortunately looks like you have to nest JSON_MODIFY statements

Comment: @SteveFord The problem is, I don't know how many properties I might need to update, so I don't know how many `JSON_MODIFY` statements to nest.